# Checking for a string/string[] to be null or "" in java

Tags: java, string

I need to check if a input `String` or a `String[]` is `null` or `""` for computing within a method in java.

This method takes argument as `String`...

I am using the below condition; can somebody check and let me know what I am wrong here,

```
if(tokens==null){
    return;
} else if(tokens[0] != null && tokens[0]!=""){
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`tokens[0]!=""` is basically comparing the memory references of `tokens[0]` and `""`, which is not what you want to do.  Instead, you need to actually check the contents of the `String`, for example

```
else if(tokens[0] != null && tokens[0].isEmpty()){
```

**Update...**

You question is a little werid...you can't have a method that takes a `String` then try and use it as an array, unless that method takes `varargs`, then you would treat it as an array anyway.

```
public boolean isEmpty(String... values) {
    boolean isEmpty = values == null || values.length == 0;
    if (!isEmpty) {
        for (String value : values) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
                isEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isEmpty;
}
```

This means you could use...

```
isEmpty("");
isEmpty("I'm not an array");
isEmpty("Check 1", "Check 2");
isEmpty(new String[]{"Check 1", "Check 2"});
```

Or similar....

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write two conditions.

You just try with `isEmpty()` ,and only one condition.

> I need to check if a input String or a String[] is null or ""

That is not possible.Either the argument will be `string` or `array`,

if `tokens`  is an array,

```
if(tokens[0] !=null && tokens[0].isEmpty()){
return;
}
```

if tokens is a String,

```
if(tokens !=null && tokens.isEmpty()){
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the method takes an argument of String (not String[]) then:

```
if(tokens == null || tokens.length() == 0) {
    return;
}
```

If the method takes an argument of String[], you need to decide if you want to check:

1. if the array is null
2. if the array contains any elements (.length == 0)
3. if any elements are null
4. if any elements are zero length

Assuming you want to check all four, you could try:

```
if(tokens == null || tokens.length == 0) {
    return;
} else {
    for(final String token : tokens) {
        if(token == null || token.length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
} else if(tokens[0] != null && tokens[0]!=""){
```

Don't you want this:

```
} else if(tokens[0] == null || tokens[0]==""){
```

I.E. the logic is inverted.

Comment: BTW, tokens[0]=="" should always work, but there may be cases in which it does not.  the isEmpty() method is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try the utility libraries that handle the check for null and empty concisely for [String](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html) and [Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html):

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(tokens))
    return; // tests that the Collection parameter is neither null nor empty

for(String token : tokens)
{
  if(!StringUtils.hasText(token)) // tests that the String parameter is neither null nor empty
    return;
}
```

Comment: handy if CollectionUtils are already in-use.  Otherise, a heavy weight solution to a simple problem.